# $\sum_{k=1}^{20}\left(3^k - 3^{k+2}\right)$ (use summation symbol properties)

Tags: summation

How to solve this summation using the summation symbol properties?

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{20}\left(3^k - 3^{k+2}\right)$$

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^{20}(a_k-a_{k+2})=a_1+a_2-a_{21}-a_{22}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

Introduce $3^{k+1}$ i.e. write
$$3^{k}-3^{k+2}=(3^k-3^{k+1})+(3^{k+1}-3^{k+2})$$
and then telescope.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n z^k=\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}$$

Take $z=3$ and we'll get,

$$\sum_{k=0}^n 3^k=\frac{1-3^{21}}{1-3}$$

$3^{k+2}=9 \times 3^k$. We'll obtain,

$$\frac{1-3^{21}}{1-3}+1-9 \times (\frac{1-3^{21}}{1-3}+1)=-41,841,412,800$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you note that the sum is a negative integer?

Comment: @Did No, edit in progress. I need to change the sign.

Comment: Yeah, and an *integer*.

Comment: @Did Thank you. Edits have been made.

Comment: It seems you are still off by a factor 3.

Comment: @Did Edited yet again.

Comment: Still wrong--let me suggest to compare with my comment on main.

Comment: I compared the two results. I compared a Maple computation to my result, I seem to be off by -8. What is my mistake in the mathematics? I can't seem to find it. @Did

Comment: The sum starts at 1, not at 0 (the 0th term is -8).

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I just figured that out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on just what summation properties you’ve learnt, but I suspect that something like the following calculation is intended:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{20}\left(3^k-3^{k+2}\right)&=\sum_{k=1}^{20}3^k-\sum_{k=1}^{20}3^{k+2}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{20}3^k-\sum_{k=3}^{22}3^k\\\\
&=3^1+3^2+\sum_{k=3}^{20}3^k-\left(\sum_{k=3}^{20}3^k+3^{21}+3^{22}\right)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Can you finish it from there?